# How to get the time between two points in time

Tags: c++, time, c++-chrono, elapsedtime

I try to get the time elapsed between two points in time in milliseconds as integer or in seconds as double. 
I'm trying to put constant acceleration of 4m/s² on something. I got this already:

```
int main() {
    double accel = 4, velocity = 0;

    auto start = chrono::system_clock::now();
    sleep(3);
    auto ende = chrono::system_clock::now();

    chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = ende - start;
    velocity += accel * elapsed_seconds;  //This is where I don't know what to put instead of "elapsed_seconds"

    cout << "Velocity after " << elapsed_seconds << "s is " << velocity << "m/s" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But as you might see it doesn't work. I already found something like

```
chrono::duration_cast<ms>(elapsed_time);
```

but I can't get it to work. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You can extract the underlying `double` from `elapsed_seconds` with `elapsed_seconds.count()`.  This will represent seconds.

Comment: `auto elapsed_seconds = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::seconds>(ende-start).count();`

Comment: Sidenote: You should probably use `steady_clock` for this since you don't want your velocity calculation to be affected by sudden changes in the `system_clock` (like clock adjustments etc).

Comment: @WhozCraig That will not return a `double`, will it? I'm thinking `double elapsed_seconds = std::chrono::duration<double>(ende - start).count();` would be better for this.

Comment: @TedLyngmo no, it won't, you're correct. Changing `seconds` to `milliseconds` will fulfill the integer option the OP apparently wants, however. Too much turkey. Still napping =P

Answer (score 3):

It's maybe a little strange to say you "count" a double but elapsed_seconds.count() will return the underlying value.

Comment: Thanks! That worked! But I don't quite understand what that does tho

Comment: It "returns the count of ticks".  Again, in this case it sounds weird because you're converting it to a double but it should basically be taking the number of "ticks" in your duration and converting it to your requested datatype and "ratio".
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/count

Answer (score 2):

To get the seconds as a double:

```
auto seconds = chrono::duration<double>(ende - start);
auto val = seconds.count();
```

To get milliseconds:

```
auto ms = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(ende - start);
auto val = ms.count();
```

Be careful when using `duration_cast`, you can lose precision.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. I like that you used my "ende". Forgot to translate the name of the variable for Stackoverflow haha